# Is logging a non-blocking operation in Spring Webflux?

Tags: maven-3, spring-webflux, project-reactor, java-11, spring-logback

Do I need to worry about logging to console, using Slf4j on top of Logback, being a blocking operation?

I wasn't sure, so I've been using `reactor.logback.AsyncAppender` from `io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-logback:3.2.3-RELEASE`

The issue I have now is that I can't compile my code using Maven as there's a transitive dependency on `com.sun.java:tools:11-internal` that can't be satisfied.  I'm not sure how to rectify this issue, so now questioning do I even need this library.

Using Spring-boot 2.1.4-RELEASE and OpenJDK 11.0.3 with Maven 3.6.0

Maven error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project yooblr-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.yooblr:yooblr-web:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.sun.java:tools:jar:11.0.3 at specified path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ch.qos.Logback.classic.AsyncAppender` can be suitable in your case. It asynchronously delegates logging to regular appenders without blocking the main thread of execution.
Its pros/cons are pretty well described in the following SO thread:
[When not to use AsyncAppender in logback by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372092/when-not-to-use-asyncappender-in-logback-by-default)

Comment: thanks, that's what I'll do. I'll see if there's a response regarding the jdk11/maven aspect.